# A single word to describe going out

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word to describe going out and doing something, which is thought through but not necessarily fully planned.

Like all of a sudden thinking "I want to go to a club" while sitting on your couch, then going out and just doing it.

A contextual example will be:

You're doing nothing and want to do something. You're presented with a list of possible chooses that may interest you. You pick one, and just do it.

Comment: Does *embark* work for you?

Comment: In most "normal" contexts we'd simply use several words (as in your own *going out and doing it*, or *putting it into practice, getting on with it*, etc.). If you insist on a single word, you might consider ***actioning** it*, but you're well into "biz-speak" jargon there.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Darren. When you get a moment click on this [Link](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and take the TOUR and also click on the HELP button on the right-side of the title bar and check–out the “help center”, if you haven’t already done so. There’s a lot to learn about this site, such as how to ask good questions and provide good answers, all about rep and site privileges. It’s well worth looking around. Anyway, you’re off to a good start. Enjoy the site and we’ll see you around, so to speak. :-)

Comment: Thanks Eva :) I think I need to update the question with better context.

Comment: Your title looks for a word for going out, but your question and  contextual example make it sound like going out is just one possible example, while the suddenness and lack of forethought of the decision are the key elements of your desired term (something like a "spur-of-the-moment" or "off-the-cuff" decision).

Comment: It's all about going out... no alternatives like "just play a pc game" - I think spur of the moment is a winner

Comment: This is pretty much the definition of "spontaneous". http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spontaneous

Comment: Also, I think your question is still ambiguous: are you trying to describe the act of going out, or of making a sudden decision?

Answer (score 2):

*[Gallivant:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gallivant)*

> 2. :  to travel, roam, or move about for pleasure

It has some diverging [connotations](https://books.google.com/books?id=Aj0RqXTKnOYC&pg=PA58&dq=%22gallivant%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=J2j3VOSmPIOryASng4KYCg&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBjgK#v=onepage&q=%22gallivant%22&f=false), but it does include idle roaming without a productive purpose:

> Gallivant. g is a fine old word, meaning, in the words of the Oxford
>   English Dictionary, "to gad about in a showy fashion, [especially]
>   with persons of the other sex." To gad means "to wander around idly,"
>   so gallivanting translates more or less as "wandering around
>   flirting"...

---

www.merriam-webster.com

*Making Whoopee: Words of Love for Lovers of Words*

Answer (score 1):

As Bilbo Baggins was fond of telling his young nephew, “*It's a dangerous business, Frodo, [venturing] out your door. You step onto the road, and if you don't keep your feet, there's no knowing where you might be swept off to.*” ― J.R.R. Tolkien, *The Lord of the Rings*

> **VENTURE** *noun* **1**. A risky or daring journey or undertaking:
>   "*pioneering ventures into little-known waters*"
>
> **VENTURE** *verb*
>   **1**. Dare to do something or go somewhere that may be dangerous or unpleasant:
>   "*she ventured out into the blizzard*"
>
> **Origin**
>   Late Middle English (in the sense ***'adventure'***, also 'risk the loss of'): shortening of adventure.
>
> **Phrases:**
>   ***at a venture***
>   **1**. *archaic* Trusting to chance rather than to previous consideration or preparation:
>   "*a man drew a bow at a venture*". see, Oxford English Dictionary [“**venture**”](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/venture)

Answer (score -2):

'running an errand' can be considered.  Free dictionary states the following
1. a short trip to accomplish a specific purpose, as to buy or deliver something or to convey a message, often for someone else.
2. the purpose of such a trip.
3. a special mission entrusted to a messenger; commission.

Comment: The connotation of "running an errand" doesn't jive well with the example provided, that of going to a club.

Comment: Errands are usually planned, and not fun (like going to a club would be)

Comment: errand being 'short' is usually unplanned.  I don't know if 'fun' component is mandatory as per the original question.

Comment: @Paul - Unless the context is dancing or playing a horn, the expression meaning “to agree with” or “to fit in” is to jibe with. Where do you hail from, Paul?

Comment: @LittleEva Nice catch. I've only heard the word said and never caught that it was "jibe", not "jive".

Comment: This may be of interest @Paul: According to Merriam-Webster, jibe is an intransitive verb meaning “to be in accord [with]”, whereas, jive is a verb: meaning either 1) to talk jive, or to fool around or 2) to dance to hot jazz, or to play hot jazz. The British Oxford English Dictionary flags jibe in the sense of “to agree with” as “chiefly U.S.” Unlike Merriam-Webster, however, the OED includes this definition under the word jive: b. intr. To make sense; to fit in. U.S. Cf JIBE v.

Comment: @Paul, ... Apparently the mistaken use of “jive” for jibe has become so widespread that it’s on the road to becoming acceptable. At least from a British viewpoint. [American English Doctor](http://americanenglishdoctor.com/wordpress/jive-and-jibe). :-)

Comment: @LittleEva Ah! No! I'm contributing to the degradation of the language! Must correct my ways... :P

Comment: Relax, @Paul, this will remain strictly between us, no one else (NSA notwithstanding) needs to know.  :-)